# Character encoding bugged after migration

Tags: centos6, migration, charset

I'm facing a nightmarish situation trying to fix my website's character encoding. Latin characters like á, é, ô, ã all turn to �

This is my website's structure:

I have 3 systems running my website, 2 of them has the bug, one not.

```
1 - mysite.com, using plain HTML/PHP = BUGGED
2 - mysite.com, using platform WHMCS = BUGGED
3 - mysite.com/blog, using platform Wordpress = WORKS FINE
```

Examples 1 and 2 are in the same folder because I can access index.php, wich is plain/html, but I can access clientarea.php, wich is WHMCS, without necessarily having to go to a sub-folder.

Now I ask, what the heck might be going on? Already tried a lof of things.

Just tranfered my dedicated server to a new one, this issue appeared now, and from the 30 websites I have, only this one is bugging like this

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the case, i would suggest to define the `charset` as `utf-8` in the `<meta>` tag of your web page.

Something like this :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
.....
</head>
```